# how remove tag request generated from wsimport?

Tags: jax-ws, wsimport

I need to remove a tag from request generated by wsimport. In the SOAP UI I have this xml request (i commented this tag for it work </get:l7OrderId-->):

```
<get:GetFAOpenBalanceRequest>
     <get:ar7AccountIDInfoDt>
        <get:accountId>700001142</get:accountId>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <!--get:l7OrderId></get:l7OrderId-->
     </get:ar7AccountIDInfoDt>
  </get:GetFAOpenBalanceRequest>
```

So, how can i comment this tag `<!--get:l7OrderId></get:l7OrderId-->` on `jax-ws` and `wsimport` client? This service works for me without this tag.

thanks for you help

Comment: The tag represents a field that is present in the wsdl you're importing. To remove it, you'll need to save a local copy of the wsdl, edit it to remove the field from the xsd and then run wsimport on the local copy of the webservice

Comment: ingenious idea, i will try and tell you... thanks for the comments